# Can std::vector be treated like an array

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Can a `std::vector<char>` be treated like an array in this way:

```
std::vector<char> v(10);
strncpy(&v[0], "hello", 9); // <-- Is this safe?
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to type std::vector<char>. Let me try to edit my original post.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: That's not how `strncpy` works...

Comment: I know the question is quite simple and straight, but you should not count on the title alone to make up the question and add a real question body that, well, asks a question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. As of C++03, `vector` is required to have contiguous storage.

As of C++11, the same is true for `std::string`, by the way; and you can say `v.data()` as a synonym for `&v[0]` (which is also valid when `v` is empty).

Comment: Your mention of *As of C++03..* gives me a doubt about how it is in C++11, So just to confirm AFAIK, `std::Vector`is still required to have contiguous storage even in C++11, Is that correct?

Comment: @Als Yes, that hasn't changed in C++11.

Comment: Yes. The new standard does not change `vector`'s storage requirements. In English, "as of" roughly means the same thing as "since", but implies a more recent timeframe for the event. :)

Comment: While this question deals with vector<char>. It's probably worth noting here that vector<bool> does not satisfy the property that you can do bool foo=&v[0]; This is because it is really a different class that implements a bit compacted mode of storage and its operator[] returns a proxy handle.  As wikipedia states, "this is widely considered a mistake," but since it is in the standard, we have to be aware of it! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B)#vector.3Cbool.3E_specialization

Comment: 'As of' does not mean the same thing as 'since'. It means 'at least until'. "As of this morning A was true" means that A was true this morning but may no longer be true. @AlokSave's question was justified.